# How to make SWR only fetch data when user changes date values?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, swr

I'm trying to use SWR, and while it's awesome, it keeps fetching data over and over.

I want it to only fetch data again when there has been change to the time interval.

I have been trying to use mutate to achieve this, but it looks like it's not the right approach. Referencing this post [Too many re-renders when setting state - useSWR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640405/too-many-re-renders-when-setting-state-useswr)

```
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { useState } from 'react';

import { apiRequest } from '../../../util/util';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import groupBy from 'lodash/groupBy';

const fetchSentiment = async (url) => {
  let sentiments = await apiRequest(url);
  sentiments = sentiments.map((el) => ({
    ...el,
    createdDay: format(new Date(el.created * 1000), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
  }));
  sentiments = groupBy(sentiments, 'createdDay');
  return sentiments;
};

export default function useAnalytics() {
  let d = new Date();
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);

  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([d.getTime(), Date.now()]);
  const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;
  const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(true);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    //Clean up this code
    if (e[0] != null && e[1] != null) {
      e[0] = e[0].getTime();
      e[1] = e[1].getTime();
    }
    setDateRange(e);
    setShouldFetch(true);
  };

  const { data: sentimentData, error: sentimentError } = useSWR(
    shouldFetch
      ? `xxx=${startDate}&endTime=${endDate}`
      : null,
    fetchSentiment
  );

  const { data: expressionsData, error: expressionsError } = useSWR(
    shouldFetch
      ? `xxx=${startDate}&endTime=${endDate}`
      : null,
    apiRequest
  );

  if (psychometricError || sentimentError || expressionsError) {
    console.log(psychometricError);
  }

  return {
    sentimentData,
    expressionsData,
    overall,
    handleChange,
    setDateRange,
    // sentimentStatistical,
    startDate,
    endDate,
  };
}
```

How can I reduce the total amount of queries, but still have it update when a new time frame is chosen?

I was thinking of using a `useEffect` to monitor the change in `dateRange` and then make `shouldFetch` true?

Comment: You can define a refresh interval so that your query will be considered "fresh" for a longer period, thereby reducing the fetching operations. You can do it passing the refresh interval as a thrid argument, like: `useSWR('/api/todos', fetcher, { refreshInterval: 1000 })`.
You can also pass the option `revalidateOnFocus: false,` to prevent re-fetching when you focus the screen after leaving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you only want to fetch new data in both `useSWR` calls when the `dateRange` values change.

You can start by replacing `useSWR` with [`useSWRImmutable`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#disable-automatic-revalidations) to disable the automatic revalidation done by SWR. You can then use an array as the `key` parameter in the `useSWRImmutable` calls to include `startDate` and `endDate`. This forces the fetcher function to re-run every time one of these variables is modified.

Here's a small refactor of your original code that implements the above suggestions, and also removes the need for the extra `shouldFetch` state variable.

```js
import useSWRImmutable from 'swr/immutable';

export default function useAnalytics() {
    const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState(() => {
        const d = new Date();
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
        return [d.getTime(), Date.now()];
    });
    const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if (e[0] != null && e[1] != null) {
            e[0] = e[0].getTime();
            e[1] = e[1].getTime();
        }
        setDateRange(e);
    };

    const { data: sentimentData, error: sentimentError } = useSWRImmutable(
        // Pass an array that includes `startDate` and `endDate`
        [`xxx=${startDate}&endTime=${endDate}`, startDate, endDate],
        fetchSentiment
    );

    const { data: expressionsData, error: expressionsError } = useSWRImmutable(
        // Pass an array that includes `startDate` and `endDate`
        [`xxx=${startDate}&endTime=${endDate}`, startDate, endDate],
        apiRequest
    );

    if (psychometricError || sentimentError || expressionsError) {
        console.log(psychometricError);
    }

    return {
        sentimentData,
        expressionsData,
        overall,
        handleChange,
        setDateRange,
        startDate,
        endDate
    };
}
```